# Get definition of stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've tried various incantations of the following query, but for the life of me can't figure out what I can't get the definition of the stored procedure back from regular ADO.NET

```
declare @procName varchar(100) = 'spGetMerchantSDR'
declare @Def varchar(max)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null 
    drop table #temp

select @Def = m.[definition]
from sys.procedures p
inner join sys.sql_modules m on p.object_id = m.object_id
where p.name = @procName

select @Def as ProcText
```

Snippet of the program

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(neededString))
{
    con.Open();

   using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdText, con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                item.Definition = rdr["ProcText"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the query in SSMS, I get the expected result. If I change the query to return everything from `sys.sql_modules`, I can get the values for things like `object_id`, but every time from C# the definition comes back as an empty string. When I run it in SSMS I get the expected result.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's with the temp table dance? Why not just `select [definition] as ProcText from sys.sql_modules where [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@procName)`? (Parameterizing the statement is a good idea.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried that, I got an empty string in code.  I tried all kinds of machinations, thinking maybe there was a particular shortcoming I wasn't aware of.

Comment: No, going through a temp table is definitely not necessary. Have you checked the more basic things, like this code running under an account that has permission to see the procedure's definition, running in the correct database, running on the correct server?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't know how to check if the account has permissions to see the definition.  It's the connection string for one of our environments that can create, alter and execute procs, though.

Comment: What does `string procText = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("ProcText"))` do for you? If you breakpoint on that, is there anything in `procText`? (Check `procText.Length` if you have to.) I'm pretty sure you can't check for the permission explicitly (because, well, security issue) but if there's an explicit user name/pw in the connection string, use that in SSMS to get the same results.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you can go ahead and close the question.  I logged in as the service account and it does not, in fact, have perms to read the definition.

Comment: I can't close anything, I could only cast a vote at best :-), but you could choose to self-answer with that, or delete the question outright. (I think it might have some value for future readers, but it's your call.)